# Server doesn't add address and port to hashmap

Tags: java, networking, udp, client-server

I have a program wHich puts the inetAddress and port for each client connected to the UDP server in a hashmap. The reason for this is so i can take messages from clients send them to the server and send them over to some other clients inside the hashmap.

However when i do this it only puts it only once inside the hashmap. How could i make it so for every new client it would add a `HashMap<InetAdress, Integer>` for every new client connection?

server:

```
private static int port = 9001;
private static HashMap<InetAddress, Integer> clients = new HashMap<InetAddress, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket(9002);
    System.out.println("[SERVER] UDP Server successfully launched on port: " + port);

    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

    

    while (true) {
        UDPSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        
            while(true) {
                InetAddress ip = receivePacket.getAddress();
                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                
                clients.put(ip, port);
            }
    }

}
```

client:

```
public ChatClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    DatagramSocket UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String message = scanner.nextLine();
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
                
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, ip, 9002);
        UDPSocket.send(packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the server code you never exit the inner `while(true)` therefore repeatedly putting the same IP and port into the map. It appears that inner loop is not needed.

Comment: It would make more sense to use  a `HashSet<SocketAddress`> obtained from `DatagramPacket.getSocketAddress()`. You shouldn't assume there is only one client per IP address, and there is no need to.